# Using CompletableFuture with RxJava abstractions

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java

Is it a good practice to use CompletableFuture with RxJava abstractions in web application? And if not, what kind of problems I might face using these things together?

Also I would like to know in general, What kind of abstractions to use with RxJava to make my code not only reactive but also asynchronous according to the best practices?

Answer (score 0):

RxJava provides a few methods to naturally bridge the gap between Rx and code that uses Futures:

```
io.reactivex.Observable.fromFuture(Future<? extends String>, Scheduler)
io.reactivex.Single.toFuture()
```

I believe RxJava3 has added better support for `CompletableFuture`, but I haven't tried it yet:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-3.0